# Image not being set in method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, uiimageview

I have a class with a viewDidLoad method and an artworkInfo method as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    mainDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];   

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)artworkInfo:(NSNumber *)pos{
    mainDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];   

[self.image setImage:(UIImage *)[[mainDelegate.mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:0]image]];

}
```

the mainDelegate thing is to gain access to the appDelegate where an array is stored, but anyway, with the "[self.image setImage...]" command where it is, the image on the app does not appear, but when I copy that exact line of code into the viewDidLoad method, it shows up like it should. I know that the artworkInfo method is being called because I debugged it and it goes through, so I can't figure out why the command would not be doing anything it's current method while it will in the viewDidLoad...?

Also, here is where the method is called and this new view is loaded from another class:

```
infoPage *info = [[infoPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"infoPage" bundle:nil];
    info.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:info animated:YES];
    infoPage *myInfoPage = [[infoPage alloc] init];
    [myInfoPage artworkInfo:position];
    [info release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OH, I see the problem.  You're instantiating 2 different `infoPage` classes.

Change this:

```
infoPage *info = [[infoPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"infoPage" bundle:nil];
info.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:info animated:YES];
infoPage *myInfoPage = [[infoPage alloc] init];
[myInfoPage artworkInfo:position];
[info release];
```

to this:

```
infoPage *info = [[infoPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"infoPage" bundle:nil];
info.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:info animated:YES];
[info artworkInfo:position];
[info release];
```

Comment: Just noticed that, yea that would definitely be a problem as well

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I've been staring at this for far too long with no clue what was wrong. It's always a dumb mistake... and @davydotcom thanks so much for the detailed explanation, although it was a bit over my head at this point:)

Answer (score 1):

Ok detailed answer. In order to understand why this image is not displaying properly you have to first look at how Runloops work in Objective C.

While viewDidLoad is the method that is called when a view is loaded and it is technically also called before a view is displayed and it's view objects initialized. Since presentModalViewController is an animation there is actually some threading going on in the works.

viewDidLoad gets called before the animation is created for the presentModalView. This initializes your objects. However, due to some of the inner workings of UI Kit some processes are loaded off into a thread. When they complete they run callback methods on the main UI thread.

Since presentModalViewController is a non-blocking method your artworkInfo method gets added to the mainRunLoop before the initializer form thread adds its callback methods to the main run loop. The best approach would be to have both a UIImage property of your viewController and a UIImageView.

set the value of UIImage by calling artworkInfo BEFORE  the presentModalViewController method.

in your ViewDidLoad go ahead and set the value of your UIImageView

```
[self.imageView setImage:self.image];
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty straight forward.

So you initialize your nib and try to call your method artwork before the nib is fully loaded. <-- This is not working for you.

Then you do additional initialization by overrider viewDidLoad per the doco where the nib is loaded <-- This is working for you

So the answer is, when you call setImage before your nib is loaded, then there is nothing to set the image to. When you call setImage in viewDidLoad your nib is loaded and then things should work just fine.

I hope this explains it a bit.

Comment: I think that makes sense. But if the viewDidLoad is being called before artwork(according to the debugger) is it still possible that the nib is still not loaded?

Comment: Well, not sure on the backend workings but you can view the Call Stack and see what is called and when more specifically. Per the documentation it mentions this: "This method is called after the view controller has loaded its associated views into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the views were stored in a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView method. This method is most commonly used to perform additional initialization steps on views that are loaded from nib files."

Comment: Hmm, well that sounds like it should be done by the time of the next method call so I don't know what could be happening. I would just do the command in the viewDidLoad method, but I was going to replace the hardcoded array index with the pos parameter, so I'm not sure how else to do this:/